# XML - where node has same name but different values

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to read an xml file (and later import the data in to a sql data base) which contains employees names address' etc.
The issue I am having is that in the xml the information for the address for the employee the node names are all the same.

```
<Employee>
 <EmployeeDetails>
   <Name>
     <Ttl>Mr</Ttl>
     <Fore>Baxter</Fore>
     <Fore>Loki</Fore>
     <Sur>Kelly</Sur>  
   </Name>
   <Address> 
     <Line>Woof Road</Line>
     <Line>Woof Lane</Line>
     <Line>Woofington</Line>
     <Line>London</Line> 
   </Address>   
    <BirthDate>1985-09-08</BirthDate>   
    <Gender>M</Gender>
    <PassportNumber>123756rt</PassportNumber>   
    </EmployeeDetails>
</Employee>
```

I all other items are fine to extract and I have tried to use Linq to iterate through each "Line" node but it always just gives be the first Line and not the others.

```
 var xAddreesLines = xEmployeeDetails.Descendants("Address").Select(x => new
   {
     address = (string)x.Element("Line").Value

   });
     foreach (var item in xAddreesLines)
       {
          Console.WriteLine(item.address);
       }
```

I need to able to when I'm importing to my sql db that address line is separate variable
eg

var addressline1 = first `<line>` node

var addressline2 = second `<line>` node etc etc.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you the expected output:-

```
var xAddreesLines = xdoc.Descendants("Address")
                        .Elements("Line")
                        .Select(x => new { address = (string)x });
```

You need to simply fetch the `Line` elements present inside `Address` node and you can project them. Also note there is no need to call the `Value` property on node when you use [explicit conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Key aspect here: `.ElementS(...)`

Comment: perfect! Thanks very much Rahul :)

Comment: @RahulSingh, It worked great, but If i want to just get one of the lines I cant get it to work. e.g.,  Console.WriteLine(item.address.ElementAt(0)); will just show me the first letter of each line address, any idea how I would get just the first line?

Comment: @CM99 - If you want just the first line why you are iterating over the collection? Simply say - `Console.WriteLine(xAddreesLines.First().address);` To avoid error use _FirstOrDefault_ (in case there in no line node) and handle nulls properly.

Comment: @RahulSingh, thanks, I will need each line assigned to a separate variable for importing in to a sql db. the Employee table of the db has a separate column for addressline1, addressline 2 etc. (sorry quite new to linq and xml)

Comment: @CM99 - Okay so what is the issue now? While iteration you can fetch each line.

Comment: @RahulSingh, no issue any more, you have been a great help!! thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
using System.Xml;
            .
            .
            .
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("source.xml");
            // if you have the xml in a string use doc.LoadXml(stringvar)
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmngr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            XmlNodeList results = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("child::Employee", nsmngr);
            foreach (XmlNode result in results)
            {
                XmlNode namenode = result.SelectSingleNode("Address");
                XmlNodeList types = result.SelectNodes("line");
                foreach (XmlNode type in types)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(type.InnerText);
                }
                XmlNode fmtaddress = result.SelectSingleNode("formatted_address");
            }
```

Refer to this [question](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/446392/accessing-xml-subnodes-with-same-name-using-linq-in-c) for the original source.